# APC Smart UPS serial connection on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, serial, apc, apc-smart-ups

I have an APC UPS 620 and a Windows Server 2012 R2 (non virtual) server. The server and the UPS are connected with genuine APC serial signaling cable.

1. Without installing any software the APC is *not* recognized as a device in the Device Manager. Is that normal/expected? I've read that USB connected APCs are recognized.
2. How can I monitor that APC from the server? I recently installed the latest PowerChute Business Edition (v9.2 for 5 node), but I don't see the APC listed either during the installation process. As far as I understand this latest version may not support serial signaling at all?

Some search shows that PowerChute v7.05 supports serial signaling but that version dates back to 2007, so way back before 2012 existed.

What's the best method to monitor my APC UPS in this case?

Comment: A serial connection in 2016? Good luck finding something that supports it...

Comment: The Dell server was bought last year and has serial. I'm fiddling with `apcupsd` right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configured http://www.apcupsd.com/ so far, http://www.apcupsd.com/manual/manual.html#a-simple-configuration-for-a-serial-smartups works

```
UPSCABLE smart
UPSTYPE apcsmart
DEVICE COM1
UPSCLASS standalone
UPSMODE disable
```

Also possible to add email sending, useful links:

1. http://www.miqrogroove.com/blog/2011/installing-apcupsd-for-windows/
2. http://www.packetwatch.net/documents/guides/2010030801.php

Answer (score 1):

Is the APC Serial Cable recognized in the Device Manager? I remember there being a problem with the driver for my system (Windows 10 in that case).

Link to the driver:
http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=225&pcid=41

The serial cable on my system:
[Prolific APC USB to Serial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfL5l.png)

Comment: How does your cable look like? Does it look like RS 232 physically? Or do you actually use an USB converter?

Comment: I could get it working with `apcupsd` (see my answer), without having any device recognized.

Comment: It's a proprietary USBtoSerial Cable: [APC Serial Cable](http://imgur.com/cNQxOKA)

Comment: Good to know, thanks! So with that cable I can use PowerChute too?